# Error ejecutando una consulta en python con sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla. **Este es el código que hice:**

```
cursor=connection.cursor()  
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TopOperadores (imsi_pref_top,descarga_top,transferencia_top) VALUES (SELECT imsi_num, AVG(descarga), AVG(transferencia) FROM Trafico_de_Datos group by nomb_oper)')
```

**Este es el error:**

> syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 1:
>   ..._pref_top,descarga_top,transferencia_top) VALUES (SELECT ims...

Comment: Es un error de SQL y no de Python. Te sugiero que ejecutes la consulta directamente en tu administrador de bases de datos y una vez que te asegures que funciona, la pases a tu código en Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario agregar `VALUES` a tu query ya que determinaste 3 campos en los cuales se insertaran los valores del `SELECT`, lo correcto sería:

```
INSERT INTO TopOperadores (imsi_pref_top,descarga_top,transferencia_top) 
SELECT imsi_num, AVG(descarga), AVG(transferencia) FROM Trafico_de_Datos group by nomb_oper
```

Comment: Cuando hago eso q me dices me pone este error:
relation "topoperadores" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO TopOperadores (imsi_pref_top,descarga_top,transf...
pero esa tabla yo si la tengo creada... q puedo ahcer ??